# Python: Access violation error while importing dll

Tags: python, dll, import, ctypes, access-violation

I've got dll to communicate with some hardware. I want to load this to python. To wrapp the dll I have written class to handle it. Reduced but working: OOspec.py

```
# file OOSpec.py

from ctypes import *
import os

# types definitions
c_double_p = POINTER(c_double)
c_OOSpec_p = POINTER(c_ulong) # to ma byt proste pointer. 
                              # Pointer by snad mel mit rozsah unsigned int. 
c_int_p = POINTER(c_int)

class Device(Structure):        
    _fields_ = [("spectro", c_OOSpec_p), 
                ("smoothLen", c_int), 
                ("winStart", c_int), 
                ("winEnd", c_int), 
                ("wvlns", c_double_p), 
                ("Dwvlns", c_double_p), 
                ("spectrum", c_double_p), 
                ("SNspectrum", c_double_p), 
                ("NDspectrum", c_double_p), 
                ("specLen", c_int)]

DEV = POINTER(Device)

class OOSpec:

    def __init__(self):
        # library load
        self.Bandidll = CDLL("BanditTDll.dll")
        # initialisation of return variables
        OOBandit_init = self.Bandidll.OOBand_init
        OOBandit_init.restype = DEV
        # instrument initialization
        self.device = OOBandit_init()

    def closeDevice(self):
        self.Bandidll.OOBand_destroy(self.device)

def whatever():
    A = OOSpec()
    A.closeDevice()

#whatever()
```

Function `whatever` serves for testing. If uncommented, script executes without error.

Now, if I import this class to other script and try the same, dll returns "access violation writing"

here is attempt to load it:

```
from OOSpec.OOSpec import *

device = OOSpec()
```

Executing the constructor triggers the error. I have checked inside the DLL. Everything is called normaly except when dll wants to write to memory allocated during its call.

Any help will be appreciated, I don't understand why the same code is called without error from one file, but triggers error from another file. I am not even sure where to look for the source of the problem.

Windows 7, 64 bit, Python 3.2. DLL written and tested in MSVC++ 2008 ExpressEddition

Comment: I'm trying my luck here but meaby it's a namespace problem? try `import OOSpec` and `device = OOSpec.OOSpec()` instead on your code.

Comment: If Windows raises an access violation in the call to `OOBand_init`, ctypes has an exception handler that routes it to a `WindowsError`. Or is the process crashing with the Windows exception dialog?

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd move loading the library and defining the function prototypes out of `__init__`. It only needs to be done once, in the module or class definition.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not remember anymore.